# slideUp and slideDown not working via jQ change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is some simple code that isn't working.

i have select option menu that uses jQuery change function to trigger.
The Textarea's default display is set to none.

The select option has only 2 values. If the second value 'Yes' is selected the Textarea slidesUp, this part works,

but if changed back to the default value of 'No', the Textarea should slide back up, i.e. slideUp() but it does not. the alert indicates that the change function is firing and the val variable is being set, but i don't understand with the slideUp function doesn't fire.

```
<style type="text/css">
textarea.someClass {
height:100px;
width:220px;
display:none;
}</style>
<select class="initials">
<option value="no">Initials? No</option>
<option value="yes">Initials? Yes</option>  
</select><br/>
<textarea class="someClass">Put instructions here </textarea>
<script>$('select').change(function(){
    theVal = $('select.initials').val();

    if(theVal == 'yes') {
        $('textarea.someClass').slideUp();
    } else if (theVal != 'yes') {
        $('textarea.someClass').slideDown();
        //$('.mtsa').css('display', 'none');
    }
})</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS was a little off - http://jsfiddle.net/tAfU5/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('select.initials').change(function(){
    var theVal = $(this).val();

    if(theVal == 'yes') {
        $('textarea.someClass').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('textarea.someClass').slideUp();
    }
}).trigger('change');
</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate some? The JSFiddle works as intended, how doesn't work with what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a mismatch with the default value, and the behavior of the sliding. By default, no is selected, and so we'd expect the `textarea` to be visible. To see this works, select yes, then select no again. The `textarea` is now visible. So I'm guessing one of two things is the case:

1. You've mismatched `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`. `slideDown()` shows an element, while `slideUp()` hides it. Simply switch these two.
2. You want **yes** to be displayed by default. To do this, add `selected` to the second `<option>` tag.